# RJS returns plain javascript without JS tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, javascript, rjs

Here is code on view in FeesController "show" action template:

```
<div id="payers_controls">
      <%= link_to_remote('New payer',
                               :update => "payers_controls", 
                               :url => new_payer_url) 
      %>
</div>
```

Here is new.rjs - belongs to PayersController "new" action

```
page.replace_html "payers_controls", :partial => "form", :object => @payer
```

Here is "new" action in PayersController

```
  def new
    @payer = Payer.new(params[:payer])
  end
```

Here is "form" partial for "new" action in PayersController

```
   <%= "Damn text to see if this damn partial is rendered properly" %>
```

And then I click "New payer" link, it renders me plain JS inside "payers_controls" DIV:

```
try { Element.update("payers_controls", "Damn text to see if this damn partial is rendered properly"); } catch (e) { alert('RJS error:\n\n' + e.toString()); alert('Element.update(\"payers_controls\", \"Damn text to see if this damn partial is rendered properly\");'); throw e }
```

And why the hell this damn response is not enclosed in SCRIPT tags?
Do I need to create another hidden placeholder with SCRIPT tags in page for JS responses?

P.S. Please understand my fury, because I'm new at AJAX on Rails, I want to be pedant programmer and, hell, I want my code to look nice and clean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to update the content twice using JS.

I would remove the :update parameter from your link_to_remote tag, or remove the RJS template.

Basically Rails is updating the page once using the RJS Template, then it is updating it again using the :update callback from the link_to_remote.  You don't need both.  Since its better to keep as little as code as possible in your views, I would remove it there and keep the RJS template.

Hope this helps.  Anything else, just let me know.

Kent

Comment: That was shrewd. Thanks a lot. Seems I need to get some sleep.

P.S. Stackoverflow is kinda addicting for such fast answers :D

Comment: Haha. No problem!  I know this is what is frustrating about JS and Rails... the devil's in the details. Good luck with your Rails project.